# log4j2 doesn't save to log file

Tags: java, log4j2

I have configuration for log4j2 in properties file. Logger sends output to the console but not to the file. It creates log file but it doesn't update it with content. What can be missing in my configuration file?

log4j2.properties

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = /usr/local/logs/kit.log

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = org.kit
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Test class

```
package org.kit.log;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest {
    private static final Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(LogTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Hello world - debug log");
        logger.info("Hello world - info log");
        logger.warn("Hello world - warn log");
        logger.error("Hello world - error log");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the first line in the configuration to `status = TRACE` to show Log4j2 internal logging on the console. This may help determine any problems with the configuration.

Also, can you try configuring a rootLogger instead of a named logger?

```
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```